# With Sed, awk or tr, how to add a newline after a specific character?

Tags: awk, sed, tr

I have this file:

```
lol.txt:hungrylol2.txt:hungry
lol3.txt:hungry
lol4.txt:hungry
lol5.txt:hungrylol6.txt:hungry
```

And I would like to turn in into this one:

```
lol.txt:hungry
lol2.txt:hungry
lol3.txt:hungry
lol4.txt:hungry
lol5.txt:hungry
lol6.txt:hungry
```

I already investigated with sed, tr and awk but did not find a convienient way to do it.

Thank you

Comment: So what's the specific character? _After_ a `y`, or _before_ a `l`? Please clarify by directly updating the question. Showing a failed solution attempt may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed using BRE:

```
sed 's/\(hungry\)\(.\)/\1\n\2/' file
```

When `hungry` is followed by one character, output it with a new line and the captured character.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
awk '{gsub(/hungrylol/,"hungry\nlol");print}'   Input_file
```

I am globally substituting the string hungrylol with hungry then new line and lol and then printing the line of Input_file.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new line after "hungry" if there was not one:

```
$ sed -r 's/(hungry)([^\n])/\1\n\2/g' file
lol.txt:hungry
lol2.txt:hungry
lol3.txt:hungry
lol4.txt:hungry
lol5.txt:hungry
lol6.txt:hungry
```

This matches `hungry` followed by a character that is not a new line. When this happens, it replaces it by `hungry` + new line + that captured character.